# Any difference between IS INITIAL and = 0 for integer?

Tags: abap

Is there any real difference between "IF integer IS INITIAL" and "IF integer = 0" in ABAP? I mean, the initial value in the I type is 0 instead of NULL, so the result is the same, isn't it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no functional difference.

The only difference is that if you ever change the type of the variable you are testing, the meaning might change. E.g. if you change it to a character based type the initial value will be `SPACE`.

Comment: Thats what i though... but then there is no way to know if the variable has been not initialized or if it was just put to 0 (or space or the type default value), right? And thanks.